# Create a JSON reading recursively from another unknown JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to read recursively all nodes from a generic JSON (so I'm not asking for a script that handles exclusively this kind of structure) and while reading I would to create another JSON in a structure like this (the example is just an excerpt):

```
[
   {
      "name":"AgreementOffer",
      "size":20000000,
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"Name",
            "size":2000000,
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"1cap",
                  "size":90
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Context",
            "size":2000000,
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"AgreementInitiator",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"$SPECS-CUSTOMER",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"AgreementInitiator",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"$SPECS-CUSTOMER",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"AgreementResponder",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"$SPECS-APPLICATION",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"AgreementResponder",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"$SPECS-APPLICATION",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"ServiceProvider",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"AgreementResponder",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"ServiceProvider",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"AgreementResponder",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"ExpirationTime",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"2014-02-02T06:00:00",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"ExpirationTime",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"2014-02-02T06:00:00",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"TemplateName",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"Y2-APP-TEMPLATE",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"TemplateName",
                  "size":200,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"Y2-APP-TEMPLATE",
                        "size":100
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
         ]
         }
]
```

So, I ask you for a script be able to handle a generic JSON (unknown structure and deep) and create another JSON written with the above structure.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I've done only the recursive script. It's be able to read all node but I'm stucked in create objects and add it to the new JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it at https://jsfiddle.net/zqkdq5mf/1/

```
function AppendObject(obj) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(obj) + ":" + JSON.stringify(obj).length);

    var Summary = null;
    for (var propertyName in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[propertyName] === "object" && !Summary) {
        Summary = { name: propertyName.toString(), size: JSON.stringify(obj).length, children: [] };

      for (var childPropertyName in obj[propertyName]) {
        var Child = {};
        Child[childPropertyName] = obj[propertyName][childPropertyName];
        Summary.children[Summary.children.length] = AppendObject(Child);
      }
      break;
    } else if (!Summary) Summary = { key: propertyName, value: obj[propertyName], size: JSON.stringify(obj).length };
  }

  return Summary;
}

function Convert() {
    $(".data").empty();
    var ParsedJSON = $.parseJSON($("textarea").val()),
        ObjectArray = [],
        Summaries = [];

    if (!(ParsedJSON instanceof Array)) ObjectArray[0] = ParsedJSON;
    else ObjectArray = ParsedJSON;

    for (var i = 0; i < ObjectArray.length; i++) Summaries[Summaries.length] = AppendObject(ObjectArray[i]);

    $(".data").text(JSON.stringify(Summaries));
}
```

Comment: Thank you man! Very useful! Your script works perfectly! I appreciate your reply and I renew my thanks for you!